# Linux kernel dropping UDP packets on addresses shared by multiple processes

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, multicast

Consider the following:

A server with multiple processes listening to the same multicast address.  The processes are able to handle the packets at varying rates.

From observation, the policy for dropping packets when the slowest process forces the rx buffer to queue is to drop the newest incoming packet. This results in all processes losing data as opposed to the slow process losing data.

I haven't been able to find any documentation outlining the policy in the linux kernel for this situation.

Is anyone aware of a way to drop the oldest packet in the buffer and allow the newest to be queued for processing?

FYI kernel 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: This could be a programming question, if there is a Linux API to specify packet-dropping policy.

Comment: I suppose one approach would be to dedicate a fast/high-priority process to do nothing but read multicast packets and forward them to the other processes.  Then you could design the forwarding-process to have any packet-dropping policy you want it to have.